# Cannot import an Android project from Eclipse to Android Studio after building a build.gradle file

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I generated a Gradle file of an Android project from Eclipse, to keep working on the project in Android Studio. Then I imported the Gradle file to open the project in Android Studio, but very confusingly it failed to build the project, showing the following message.

```
Error:SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

I have been working on other Android projects in Android Studio with no problems in this issue, so I become too much confused. I also searched the questions regarding the same matter, but none of them seemed to clearly suggest the solution.

In order to make you better understand, I show you several things related to building the project.

**1. build.gradle**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

and

```html
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    }
```

```html
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"
```

```html
sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

**2. local.properties**

```
sdk.dir=/Users/marshall/android-sdks
```

The Android SDK is properly installed in that direction above. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IMPORTING ECLIPSE PROJECT IN ANDROID STUDIO:**

If you want to import Eclipse Project in Android Studio:

**1.** **Launch** *Android Studio* and **Select** *Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)*

**2.** Then nothing special just follow the instructions in the wizard.

**NOTE:** Just Make sure you have chosen the folder of Eclipse project that contains the **src** folder. And also ensure the target folder will be empty. 
You don't need to create `build.gradle` or export any thing from eclipse as this steps are no longer needed to Android Studio